# Dealing with test failures in Gerrit / Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, gerrit

For a small development team (6 developers) I set up Gerrit and Jenkins to allow for code review and CI. The integration between both is working fine, with Jenkins compiling and testing the code.

I'm however unable to decide how to handle failing failing tests. Currently if a test fails then the build is considered as failed as well. How would one handle that in the case of changed functionality causing a test to fail? Or when tests are improved and find broken code? Would one always fix the broken code as well, and squash the test changed and the fix into a single commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/config-labels.html

You can add an additional topic for testing, so build verification is +1 testing -1, so dividing it in categories, this requires some configuration of the jenkins jobs as the testjobs have to report back in a different manner that the build verification jobs.

But anyway it does the for me.

Comment: Do you use separate jobs for this? Great answer!

Comment: Yes we have separate jobs for testing and builds :)

Comment: I was attempting the multiple job approach, but what do you use as trigger? Do you use an upstream build project and downstream test project? Do you happen to have the details online? I'm having a hard time getting it right, or finding documentation about a proper solution.

Comment: You can do it many ways. 
1st first job is triggered by gerrit (Build software) settting +1 in verified after it is success full.
2nd job is triggered by 1st job and it is the test job which will set the auto-test topic to +1 using the gerrit command "gerrit review" if the job is passing and -1 if it is failing. 
http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/cmd-review.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, and it comes down to your development methodologies.  I prefer to keep commits as small and compact as possible, so I would want to split up the test changes and code fixes.

You could upload the code fixes first, and not upload your test changes until the code fixes are merged.  But having the test changes available is helpful for reviewers to understand why the code fixes are necessary.

If your test framework supports it, I would make the test changes first but flag the test as expected-to-fail.  Then upload the code fixes and remove the flag on that test.

Hopefully others will chime in with different solutions to this situation!

Comment: Isn't that also really error-prone? If the fix would be incorrect and you forget to remove the expected-fail, the code would still be broken. I also like to keep commits small and we adhere to gitflow as much as possible. Also, with test-driven development it's not uncommon to encounter failing tests, but my current setup doesn't allow for that...